# jsp:useBean attributes official documentation

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm a beginner at Java ee and I'm trying to learn how jsp works.

With the `<jsp:useBean>`, I want to learn a bit more about what are some of the different attributes available.

With a basic google search, I could easily find the oracle documentation on classes such as `HttpServlet, HttpServletResponse` etc. But searching the term `jsp useBean documentation` did not show up similar pages that are official oracle documentation.

I was just wondering, what is a good search strategy when I want to checkout the official Oracle documentation on JSP technology?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13226_01/workshop/docs81/pdf/files/workshop/JSPTagsReference.pdf) from oracle.

Contents from the provided link:

> The `<jsp:useBean>` tag locates or instantiates a JavaBeans component.
>   The `<jsp:useBean>` tag first attempts to locate an instance of the
>   bean. If the bean does not exist, `<jsp:useBean>` instantiates it from
>   a class or serialized template. To locate or instantiate the bean,
>   `<jsp:useBean>` takes the following steps, in this order:
>
> 1. Attempts to locate a bean with the scope and name you specify.
> 2. Defines an object reference variable with the name you specify. If it finds the bean, stores a reference to it in the variable. If you
>      specified type, gives the bean that type.
> 3. If it does not find the bean, instantiates it from the class you specify, storing a reference to it in the new variable. If the class
>      name represents a serialized template, the bean is instantiated by
>      `java.beans.Beans.instantiate`.
> 4. If `<jsp:useBean>` has instantiated (rather than located) the bean, and if it has body tags or `JSP` tags (between `<jsp:useBean>`
>      and `</jsp:useBean>`), executes the body tags.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> <jsp:useBean id="beanInstanceName" scope="page|request|session|application"
> {
>  class="package.class" [ type="package.class" ]|
>  beanName="{package.class |
>  <%= expression %>}" type="package.class" |
>  type="package.class"
> }
> { /> | > other tags </jsp:useBean> }
> ```